# Image position inside UITabBarItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I'm using code to shown a UITabBar with items, I downloaded an example that show item with system icons of "favorites" "contacts" ...

```
UITabBarItem *favorites = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil image:a1 tag:0];
UITabBarItem *topRated = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemTopRated tag:1];
UITabBarItem *featured = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemFeatured tag:2];
UITabBarItem *recents = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemRecents tag:3];
```

I want to use my own images so i changed the first line (favorites), but when i setting it, the image is starting in the middle, and always stays a small place for title,even if it's empty.

How can I controll the image possition inside those items? and disable the empty title place?

Comment: Any example of tabBar ??

Answer (score 1):

It's a fairly old question but even old questions need love :)

So if you're still having this problem you can use  the `UIViewController`s tab bar item image insets: `tabBarItem.imageInsets`.

You set this on view controllers which you will assign to `viewControllers` property of the tab bar controller.

Here is a swift version of a subclassed tab bar controller which will always ensure all images are aligned a bit lower.

```
override func setViewControllers(viewControllers: [AnyObject], animated: Bool) {
    super.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: animated)

    let array = viewControllers as! [UIViewController]
    for controller in array {
        controller.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, -5, 0)
    }
}
```